# Symfony - Form not redirecting to action specified in form

Tags: php, forms, symfony, action

I'm trying to make a form, which I self-defined the action like this in my controller:

```php
$form = $this->createForm(ProgrammeSearchType::class, $search, [
    'action' => $this->generateUrl('recherche_programme'),
    'method' => 'GET',
]);
```

But, the form rendered in the view look like this:

```
<form id="myForm">
{{fields.....}}
</form>
```

So.. there is a problem. Why "action" is not specified in the HTML while I defined it into the controller.

Regards

Symfony doc: https://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html#changing-the-action-and-http-method

Comment: Can you please share your view codes?

Comment: I just post it below ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use `{{ form_start(form) }}` and `{{ form_end(form) }}` instead of `<form> ... </form>` tags in your view template.

Comment: I currently use it. I just shown the rendered code.

{{ form_start(formResearch) }}
{{ form_end(formResearch, {'render_rest': false}) }}

Comment: Are you sure the route `recherche_programme` works? And why does it render form name `myForm` when you are using `ProgrammeSearchType` form class? I would try what would happen if you set it in template: `{{ form_start(form, {'action': path('target_route'), 'method': 'GET'}) }}`

Comment: The route "recherche_programme" works, according to the debug_router that show it.
Oh, for the ID it's me. I just edited the code for stackoverflow. The real code rendered is <form id="formRecherche">.
If I try the template solution, it's the same.. Not working.

Comment: Solved... I had an other <form> and It confused Symfony...
Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

I'm bringing back an old topic but I had a prettry similar behaviour. It looks like you need to override the "action" and "method" in the twig template. When you just only set those parameters in the controller they are not taken in account.